# Enlarging a menu from right to left

Tags: html, css

I have a div header which has a width of 100%. Inside that div i have 3 other divs: left (18% width), center (64% width) and right (18% width). Inside the left and right divs there is a button which displays a menu on hover. This works perfectly in a desktop browser, but for mobile i want to expand both menus to 50% of the page width so it's user friendly.

When i enlarge the menu from the left div it expands from left to right towards the middle of the page which is perfect. However, the menu from the right div also expands from left to right towards the end of the page making the page wider so i get a scrollbar.

I would like to have the menu from the right div also expand to the middle, i.e. from right to left.
Anyone knows how to do this with css?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.